# Regex invalid escape Javascript issue

Tags: javascript, regex

Hi Guys i have an issue with one of my regular expressions, the regular expression itself functions but i have an error appear in FireFox developer

Unable to check  because the pattern is not a valid regexp: invalid identity escape in regular expression

i am aware of identity escapes but not aware of how to apply it to this regex below

```
^(((\+44\s?\d{4}|\(?0\d{4}\)?)\s?\d{3}\s?\d{3})|((\+44\s?\d{4}|\(?0\d{4}\)?)\s?\d{5})|((\+44\s?\d{3}|\(?0\d{3}\)?)\s?\d{3}\s?\d{4})|((\+44\s?\d{2}|\(?0\d{2}\)?)\s?\d{4}\s?\d{4}))(\s?\#(\d{4}|\d{3}))?$
```

Comment: That's scary looking. It's hard to tell if it's even structured correctly. Try writing your RegEx using a tool like this: https://regex101.com/

Comment: the `+` character at the begining is your problem. There's nothing to repeat before it

Comment: By the way, Java **is not** Javascript.

Comment: in this `(?0\d{4})`, the `?0` is invalid too

Comment: It does not work because of `\#`. It must be `#`. Remove that backslash and it should work.

Comment: Thank you everyone